# Using Style or Button of an Alert

Tags: android-alertdialog, maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I created my own Popup display it via

```
Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(customPopupPage);
```

As this looks like a view you get when opening a Picker, I was thinking whether it is an option to display Buttons in the Style you can see when an Alert is displayed.

Edit:  I mean the "OK" and "Cancel"-Buttons here

[image]

Is there a style, I could use or is there a way to just display the Buttons that an Alert would use?

Comment: please post some screenshots illustrating what you are talking about

Comment: Added a screenshot above: "OK" and "Cancel"-Buttons were meant. Question is anyway if own Buttons with the UI-Button style are better in an own Popup ContentPage or take some of the "Standard-UI-Buttons"

Comment: you need a screenshot showing a) what you're currently getting and b) what you would like them to look like instead

Comment: When I add a Button, it has the Styling I defined in Styles.xml. When I display an Alert-Message it gets the Platform-Dependant Styles for OK and Cancel as you can see in the Screenshot. As I use my own Popup-ContentPage, which is an empty Page, I can only add Buttons there which have the Style defined in Styles.xml. What I consider to want is the Buttons you see on the Screenshot. Well could be done with other styles than the defined Button-Styles. But, is there a way to take the Style iOS or Android is using when it Displays an Alert-Box? That was the question

Answer (score 0):

> Question is anyway if own Buttons with the UI-Button style are better in an own Popup ContentPage or take some of the "Standard-UI-Buttons"

According to your preference. It has no distinction between good and bad. [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) was created to allow developers to build their own custom UI and present it to their users.

[The effect of following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v9Dv.jpg):

```xml
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit" 
    x:Class="MauiApp1.popup" 
    Color="Transparent">

    <Frame WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="200" CornerRadius="20">
        <StackLayout Margin="10">
            <Label Text="You want to login?" FontSize="Title"/>
            <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,60,0,0">
                <Button Text="Cancel" 
                        Clicked="OnNoButtonClicked" />
                <Button Text="Ok" 
                        Clicked="OnYesButtonClicked" 
                        Margin="10,0"/>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>

</toolkit:Popup>
```

[The effect that is similar to what an Alert is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5dNi.jpg):

```xml
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit" 
    x:Class="MauiApp1.popup" 
    Color="Transparent">

    <Frame WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="200" CornerRadius="20">
        <StackLayout Margin="10">
            <Label Text="You want to login?" FontSize="Title"/>
            <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,75,0,0">
                <Button Text="Cancel" 
                        TextColor="#512BD4" 
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                        Clicked="OnNoButtonClicked" />
                <Button Text="Ok" 
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                        TextColor="#512BD4" 
                        Clicked="OnYesButtonClicked" 
                        Margin="10,0"/>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>

</toolkit:Popup>
```

Comment: Great examples and presentation  To ne honest, looking at your first one, I am not decided yet if I should stay with my own Buttons in the corresponding Style they are set. But back to my original question, I was probably a bit misleading: The Color you‘ve set fits to Android and is same as in my Screenshot. But, let’s say the App is running on iOS. I think iOS renders and presents these UI Elements differently with its own style I don’t know yet. Is there a possibility to use this very Style for these Elements on iOS and Android or Windows phones with their style?

Comment: @OXO *Is there a possibility to use this very Style for these Elements on iOS and Android or Windows phones with their style?* Yes, you can use Handler to modify button for different platforms.

Comment: I think this should be the other way around and I want to use the Button Style and set it as Style for the Button in my own Popup Page, so that it looks like as if it was rendered by the corresponding Platform (iOS or Android). What you did in your example was exactly what Android would display, but I think iOS Buttons in Alerts are a bit more complex, so that just setting a different TextColor would not work. What I wanted to know if it is possible to get a Button-Style-Instace from the corresponding OS and I can just set this to my own Button on the PopupPage?

Comment: @OXO * What I wanted to know if it is possible to get a Button-Style-Instace from the corresponding OS and I can just set this to my own Button on the PopupPage?* Unfortunately no. Have you tested it on ios?  I tested button and it's no brush color for default.